# 'Appscale up' stuck at 'Waiting for head node to initialize'

Tags: amazon-ec2, appscale

I was trying to start appscale on ec2 instance for deploying my python app. First of all I installed appscale-tools and initiated cluster which made AppScaleFile. Then I used `appscale up` command which is stuck at this point `Waiting for head node to initialize...`. Here is the screenshot:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0GVN.png)

It is some sort of an infinite loop. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If using Ubuntu you may be running into an issue with the version of monit that they distribute, as described here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/monit/+bug/1786910

If so, then this AppScale blog has more information on workarounds:

https://blog.appscale.com/monit-bug-impacting-appscale-deployments

To check if you are using the broken monit (version 1:5.16-2ubuntu0.1):

```
# dpkg -l monit
```

To downgrade (on all hosts running AppScale):

```
# sudo apt-get install monit=1:5.16-2
# sudo apt-mark hold monit
```

Keep in mind that this is reverting a security fix, so may not always be an acceptable solution.